# Annotating images on QGIS or using widgets?

Tags: qgis, annotation, hyperlink, html-popup

I've georeferenced an old map on qgis and layered it on top of OSM, I want to do a class project and for it I would like to pinpoint certain areas on the map of which I have old photographs. I would like to know if it's possible to pinpoint the locations and attach photographs, so you can see photos of what that place used to look like, as well as write textual information. I know that you can do text annotations, but how about images?

I would like it to be something similar to like when you get locations pinpointed on google maps and when you press on the pinpoint you get the photo and information.

Answer (score -1):

Hyperlink the photos with the points, and qgis will show up a popup when you click on the points.

Comment: Perhaps expand your answer telling how to make the hyperlinks from points and add a screenshot of showing such pop up? The answer was flagged as low quality, probably because it is a one-liner. Let me know if you decide to edit it. Tks.